# Powershell 5.0 doesn't see PATH environment variables under User account

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, powershell-5.0

I added an environment variable to my `System Path` -> `C:\Program Files\TEE-CLC`. After that, I expect, that I can run my `foo.exe` which is under `C:\Program Files\TEE-CLC` from PowerShell without providing a full path to it. The issue is when I start a new, fresh Powershell session under my user, it doesn't see the newly added path, but when I start it under administrator everything works fine.

I checked `$env:Path` in both modes (`User` and `Admin`) and found that my new path doesn't exist when I am under `User`, but I can see it when Powershell is `as Administrator`

How I can make my newly added variable visible running under `User` rather than `Administrator`?

**UPDATE**
I ran 2 commands under `User` and the result is different. Why doesn't `$env:Path` display the same output as `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'MACHINE')` and why current `PSSession` doesn't see the path from the latter command?`

[image: $env:Path]

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE**

1. Add environemt path variable `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', ($env:Path + ';C:\Program Files\Foo'), 'MACHINE')`
2. Close the session
3. Open a NEW ps session as user -> check `$env:PATH` -> `C:\Program Files\Foo` **is not** there
4. Open a NEW ps session as admin -> check `$env:PATH` -> `C:\Program Files\Foo` **is** there

Comment: How did you add "C:\Program Files\FOOPATH" to the PATH variable? SETX? GUI?

Comment: @lit It was added from PS script, using `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $UpdatedPathList, 'MACHINE')`

Comment: To change the value of `Path`, you'd use this `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $Env:Path + ";C:\SomeLocation", "Machine")`, so unfortunately as you've not shown or provided the code which specifically defines the value of the `$UpdatedPathList` variable, we don't know if it contains the required information. Also you need to understand that whilst you may have added it to the System, _(Machine)_, environment, your PS Session inherits only what was defined when it started, new additions are not propagated into an existing session.

Comment: When you view the `Path` values, it will show all of those available under `Machine`, and `User`, when the PS session was opened, and any created in that session, i.e as `Process`. If you want to create a persistent variable, in `Machine` or `User`, and wish also to use it in the same session, you'd need also to define it as a `Process` variable e.g. `$Env:Path += ";C:\SomeLocation"`, or `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $Env:Path + ";C:\SomeLocation", "Process")`.

Comment: @Compo It is besides a point:

1) I explicitly provided info that I ran `The issue is when I start a new, fresh Powershell session`
2) Take a look at the picture, the path is there. Therefore, it was provided to the `SetEnvironmentVariable` function correctly. 
I think I need to provide more info because apparently, the question is not clear. Get to the STEPS TO REPRODUCE section in order to reproduce the behavior on your machine

Comment: Please see my temporary answer @managerger, where I have failed to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've missed something, I cannot reproduce your issue, here's example, I've just perfromed on a Test machine for you.

First I opened an elevated `powershell.exe` window, i.e. 'as administrator`:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Env:Path
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Tester\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', ($Env:Path + ';C:\Program Files\Foo'), 'MACHINE')
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Env:Path
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Tester\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'MACHINE')
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Tester\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Foo
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Then I opened a new non elevated `powershell.exe` window:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\Tester> $Env:Path
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Tester\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Foo;C:\Users\Tester\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
PS C:\Users\Tester> [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'MACHINE')
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Tester\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Foo
PS C:\Users\Tester>
```

As you can see `C:\Program Files\Foo` was shown in both example outputs.

Then I opened another new elevated `powershell.exe` window:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Env:Path
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Tester\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Foo;
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'MACHINE')
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Tester\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Foo
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

As you can see `C:\Program Files\Foo` was shown in both example outputs.

Comment: Thanks! It might be something env dependent. Will try to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

This issue suddenly appeared for me out of the blue and I was able to solve it for myself at least.

**Warning:** backup your PATH somewhere before running anything. There's a 1024ch limit so be careful.

### Background

As a user (non-admin), your `$Path` is the equivalent of `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'USER')` while as admin your `$Path` is the equivalent of `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'MACHINE')`. There are probably many instances where you want these separated. In my case everything under my "MACHINE" $Path are things I'd want as a regular user, so I'll just show how to combine these paths so that no matter how you run powershell you'll have the same path.

### Process

1. Open cmd.exe as an administrator (there's probably a way to do this in powershell but this method seems so much easier and will apply to powershell fine)
2. Add the combined paths to the user path:

```
setx path "%path%"
```

(within cmd `%path%` is a combination of both the user and machine paths)

3. (Extra) Add the combined paths to the system path:

```
setx /M path "%path%"
```

4. Restart powershell. The executables you expect should now be available as a user.